# Trim function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, email

In my application I need to use trim function to email Id field. When I copy email id with some white space it shows email id. Id does not match. How can I use trim() method in java script.

```js
function validateform() {
  var email1 = document.getElementById('Email').value;
  var email = trim(email1);

  //email check condition email should be in like this
  if (!(email.endsWith("@hai.com") || email.endsWith("@hello.com"))) {
    alert("Email Should be in @hi.com or @hello.com");
    $("#Email").val('');
    document.getElementById("Email").focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function trim(email2) {
  return email2.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with email.trim() ?
var email = document.getElementById('Email').value.trim(); should suffice

Comment: Your trim() function works fine, the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: There is already a String.trim() - I suggest you either use that or rename yours to something else. Also define the function before using it

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with your HTML and create a [mcve] - there are things going on not visible in the code you show

Comment: `else if`  without an if is not valid JS

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use the default string .trim() function.

```
var email = document.getElementById('Email').value.trim();
```

That's it :)

Comment: @Antony do you need <= IE8 support

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code like below,[Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```
function validateform() {
    var email1 = document.getElementById('Email').value;
    var email = email1.trim();

    //email check condition email should be in like this
    else if (!(email.endsWith("@hai.com") || email.endsWith("@hello.com"))) 
    {
       alert("Email Should be in @hi.com or @hello.com");
       $("#Email").val('');
       document.getElementById("Email").focus();
       return false;
    }
}
```

Note : The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.